# Make Gurobi make use of all cores

Tags: c, gurobi

**Description:** I wrote a program for my masters thesis that has to solve several LPs and therefore calls Gurobi as a sub function.  This call seems to be the bottleneck of the implementation since 95% of the time is spent solving the LP.
I use Gurobi and worked on my personal computer with 2,7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3 processor.
Now I am allowed to use one of the computers form my university which has 1 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz (10 Cores)
12 GB Memory.

I expected a huge performance boost but there is almost none.

**What I already tried:** I tried changing the:

- GRB_INT_PAR_THREADS
- GRB_INT_PAR_METHOD

parameters, but there still isn't much change in the performance.

One example of the log file is attached.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.1 build v9.1.1rc0 (linux64)
Thread count: 20 physical cores, 20 logical processors, using up to 20 threads
Optimize a model with 47040 rows, 234248 columns and 421456 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x5eb54e3e
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [2e+01, 1e+04]
Presolve removed 0 rows and 47040 columns
Presolve time: 0.14s
Presolved: 47040 rows, 187208 columns, 374416 nonzeros

Ordering time: 0.18s

Barrier statistics:
 AA' NZ     : 9.360e+04
 Factor NZ  : 1.281e+06 (roughly 100 MBytes of memory)
 Factor Ops : 8.199e+07 (less than 1 second per iteration)
 Threads    : 20

                  Objective                Residual
Iter       Primal          Dual         Primal    Dual     Compl     Time
   0   2.05891230e+09  0.00000000e+00  4.28e+03 0.00e+00  1.40e+04     1s
   1   7.99199355e+08  9.57896973e+05  3.45e+03 0.00e+00  3.87e+03     1s
   2   3.76984709e+08  3.06791526e+06  1.58e+03 0.00e+00  1.81e+03     1s
   3   2.17507994e+08  5.56777488e+06  8.85e+02 0.00e+00  1.03e+03     1s
   4   1.69117220e+08  7.35356168e+06  6.71e+02 0.00e+00  7.95e+02     1s
   5   1.66107116e+08  8.10683166e+06  6.58e+02 0.00e+00  7.80e+02     1s
   6   1.42775281e+08  9.11885810e+06  5.56e+02 0.00e+00  6.64e+02     1s
   7   1.30527905e+08  1.00436052e+07  5.05e+02 0.00e+00  6.04e+02     1s
   8   1.22682719e+08  1.08259037e+07  4.70e+02 0.00e+00  5.64e+02     1s
   9   1.17732427e+08  1.21074031e+07  4.48e+02 0.00e+00  5.40e+02     1s
  10   1.01230816e+08  1.31266937e+07  3.79e+02 0.00e+00  4.56e+02     1s
  11   8.84816115e+07  1.37958396e+07  3.24e+02 0.00e+00  3.90e+02     1s
  12   8.08822943e+07  1.41970742e+07  2.91e+02 0.00e+00  3.51e+02     1s
  13   7.80735443e+07  1.46924292e+07  2.78e+02 0.00e+00  3.36e+02     1s
  14   7.54425567e+07  1.51181733e+07  2.67e+02 0.00e+00  3.22e+02     1s
  15   6.81732340e+07  1.54442178e+07  2.34e+02 0.00e+00  2.83e+02     1s
  16   6.52567699e+07  1.59344337e+07  2.21e+02 0.00e+00  2.68e+02     1s
  17   5.63537328e+07  1.63419649e+07  1.81e+02 0.00e+00  2.20e+02     1s
  18   5.45568618e+07  1.66435557e+07  1.73e+02 0.00e+00  2.10e+02     1s
  19   5.18277826e+07  1.70695697e+07  1.60e+02 0.00e+00  1.95e+02     1s
  20   4.90282837e+07  1.75061425e+07  1.46e+02 0.00e+00  1.79e+02     1s
  21   4.67290813e+07  1.78044770e+07  1.35e+02 0.00e+00  1.66e+02     1s
  22   4.26935434e+07  1.80588622e+07  1.16e+02 0.00e+00  1.43e+02     1s
  23   4.09976121e+07  1.82619013e+07  1.08e+02 0.00e+00  1.34e+02     1s
  24   4.04580421e+07  1.83067660e+07  1.06e+02 0.00e+00  1.30e+02     1s
  25   3.80796646e+07  1.85633324e+07  9.44e+01 0.00e+00  1.16e+02     2s
  26   3.76709901e+07  1.86846947e+07  9.24e+01 0.00e+00  1.14e+02     2s
  27   3.51954559e+07  1.89242514e+07  8.03e+01 0.00e+00  9.89e+01     2s
  28   3.41656973e+07  1.89954450e+07  7.52e+01 0.00e+00  9.28e+01     2s
  29   3.28912756e+07  1.92260278e+07  6.89e+01 0.00e+00  8.49e+01     2s
  30   3.20983253e+07  1.94213779e+07  6.45e+01 0.00e+00  7.99e+01     2s
  31   3.14211729e+07  1.95116652e+07  6.11e+01 0.00e+00  7.57e+01     2s
  32   2.96667304e+07  1.96751105e+07  5.20e+01 0.00e+00  6.45e+01     2s
  33   2.90271887e+07  1.98540889e+07  4.86e+01 0.00e+00  6.03e+01     2s
  34   2.84261421e+07  2.00042665e+07  4.54e+01 0.00e+00  5.62e+01     2s
  35   2.79724035e+07  2.01113819e+07  4.29e+01 0.00e+00  5.31e+01     2s
  36   2.74371507e+07  2.01864588e+07  3.97e+01 0.00e+00  4.94e+01     2s
  37   2.67412113e+07  2.02413849e+07  3.58e+01 0.00e+00  4.47e+01     2s
  38   2.63019678e+07  2.03496742e+07  3.32e+01 0.00e+00  4.15e+01     2s
  39   2.59709759e+07  2.04474068e+07  3.14e+01 0.00e+00  3.92e+01     2s
  40   2.52349514e+07  2.04955855e+07  2.72e+01 0.00e+00  3.39e+01     2s
  41   2.47606481e+07  2.05694251e+07  2.44e+01 0.00e+00  3.05e+01     2s
  42   2.45219430e+07  2.05922626e+07  2.30e+01 0.00e+00  2.88e+01     2s
  43   2.41791973e+07  2.07380977e+07  2.10e+01 0.00e+00  2.61e+01     2s
  44   2.36722657e+07  2.08341283e+07  1.76e+01 0.00e+00  2.21e+01     2s
  45   2.35410657e+07  2.09570443e+07  1.67e+01 0.00e+00  2.10e+01     2s
  46   2.32812390e+07  2.09790761e+07  1.50e+01 0.00e+00  1.89e+01     2s
  47   2.30427296e+07  2.10444627e+07  1.33e+01 0.00e+00  1.69e+01     3s
  48   2.28762555e+07  2.11398052e+07  1.21e+01 0.00e+00  1.54e+01     3s
  49   2.27474204e+07  2.11969228e+07  1.12e+01 0.00e+00  1.43e+01     3s
  50   2.25195896e+07  2.12536300e+07  9.39e+00 0.00e+00  1.21e+01     3s
  51   2.23303152e+07  2.13490227e+07  7.97e+00 0.00e+00  1.03e+01     3s
  52   2.22251215e+07  2.14193508e+07  7.13e+00 0.00e+00  9.21e+00     3s
  53   2.21864602e+07  2.14632161e+07  6.81e+00 0.00e+00  8.79e+00     3s
  54   2.20864814e+07  2.15007518e+07  5.92e+00 0.00e+00  7.62e+00     3s
  55   2.20660439e+07  2.15185550e+07  5.69e+00 0.00e+00  7.34e+00     3s
  56   2.20492259e+07  2.15459904e+07  5.52e+00 0.00e+00  7.15e+00     3s
  57   2.19645299e+07  2.16082241e+07  4.66e+00 0.00e+00  6.02e+00     3s
  58   2.19334221e+07  2.16250948e+07  4.28e+00 0.00e+00  5.53e+00     3s
  59   2.18982616e+07  2.16497986e+07  3.78e+00 0.00e+00  4.88e+00     3s
  60   2.18868179e+07  2.16447062e+07  3.60e+00 0.00e+00  4.67e+00     3s
  61   2.18673452e+07  2.16733854e+07  3.31e+00 0.00e+00  4.28e+00     3s
  62   2.18322595e+07  2.16931197e+07  2.63e+00 0.00e+00  3.40e+00     3s
  63   2.18303926e+07  2.17042422e+07  2.59e+00 0.00e+00  3.34e+00     3s
  64   2.18224530e+07  2.17201714e+07  2.39e+00 0.00e+00  3.09e+00     3s
  65   2.18206818e+07  2.17272214e+07  2.35e+00 0.00e+00  3.04e+00     3s
  66   2.18196399e+07  2.17339658e+07  2.32e+00 0.00e+00  3.01e+00     3s
  67   2.18188674e+07  2.17397969e+07  2.26e+00 0.00e+00  2.93e+00     3s
  68   2.18126091e+07  2.17348009e+07  2.08e+00 0.00e+00  2.71e+00     3s
  69   2.18126592e+07  2.17435435e+07  2.04e+00 0.00e+00  2.66e+00     3s
  70   2.18059067e+07  2.17568759e+07  1.83e+00 0.00e+00  2.38e+00     3s
  71   2.18017488e+07  2.17587278e+07  1.62e+00 0.00e+00  2.11e+00     4s
  72   2.18014928e+07  2.17688525e+07  1.61e+00 0.00e+00  2.09e+00     4s
  73   2.18013265e+07  2.18000346e+07  1.56e+00 0.00e+00  2.02e+00     4s
  74   2.18030801e+07  2.18148719e+07  1.32e+00 0.00e+00  1.71e+00     4s
  75   2.18040928e+07  2.17997729e+07  1.27e+00 0.00e+00  1.66e+00     4s
  76   2.18054092e+07  2.18168314e+07  1.22e+00 0.00e+00  1.59e+00     4s
  77   2.18064954e+07  2.18043784e+07  1.18e+00 0.00e+00  1.55e+00     4s
  78   2.18089734e+07  2.18331897e+07  1.12e+00 0.00e+00  1.46e+00     4s
  79   2.18107303e+07  2.18475845e+07  1.07e+00 0.00e+00  1.39e+00     4s
  80   2.18139975e+07  2.18565554e+07  9.91e-01 0.00e+00  1.29e+00     4s
  81   2.18147929e+07  2.18652514e+07  9.80e-01 0.00e+00  1.28e+00     4s
  82   2.18182834e+07  2.18741457e+07  9.34e-01 0.00e+00  1.22e+00     4s
  83   2.18188508e+07  2.18847518e+07  9.24e-01 0.00e+00  1.21e+00     4s
  84   2.18230492e+07  2.18859168e+07  8.56e-01 0.00e+00  1.12e+00     4s
  85   2.18269300e+07  2.19091529e+07  7.99e-01 0.00e+00  1.05e+00     4s
  86   2.18298682e+07  2.19137177e+07  7.83e-01 0.00e+00  1.04e+00     4s
  87   2.18360091e+07  2.19251598e+07  7.26e-01 0.00e+00  9.59e-01     4s
  88   2.18375323e+07  2.19197556e+07  7.12e-01 0.00e+00  9.44e-01     4s
  89   2.18442774e+07  2.19289311e+07  6.66e-01 0.00e+00  8.91e-01     4s
  90   2.18456880e+07  2.19322744e+07  6.59e-01 0.00e+00  8.82e-01     4s
  91   2.18486071e+07  2.19389188e+07  6.36e-01 0.00e+00  8.55e-01     4s
  92   2.18536361e+07  2.19549627e+07  6.09e-01 7.33e-15  8.23e-01     4s
  93   2.18546736e+07  2.19558852e+07  6.02e-01 1.22e-14  8.15e-01     4s
  94   2.18575814e+07  2.19613671e+07  5.84e-01 1.69e-14  7.90e-01     5s
  95   2.18635622e+07  2.19643155e+07  5.49e-01 1.93e-14  7.42e-01     5s
  96   2.18708614e+07  2.19677184e+07  5.11e-01 2.21e-14  6.91e-01     5s
  97   2.18753342e+07  2.19716733e+07  4.88e-01 2.39e-14  6.59e-01     5s
  98   2.18762429e+07  2.19727518e+07  4.83e-01 2.20e-14  6.54e-01     5s
  99   2.18766421e+07  2.19773813e+07  4.81e-01 2.31e-14  6.51e-01     5s
 100   2.18797129e+07  2.19811051e+07  4.65e-01 2.63e-14  6.29e-01     5s
 101   2.18808257e+07  2.19856155e+07  4.60e-01 2.91e-14  6.23e-01     5s
 102   2.18858420e+07  2.20018334e+07  4.38e-01 2.69e-14  5.94e-01     5s
 103   2.18875234e+07  2.20041877e+07  4.31e-01 3.05e-14  5.84e-01     5s
 104   2.18879031e+07  2.20110592e+07  4.30e-01 3.13e-14  5.84e-01     5s
 105   2.05891230e+09  0.00000000e+00  4.28e+03 0.00e+00  1.10e+07     5s
 106   3.41558899e+09  8.61733524e+08  1.49e+03 1.29e+02  2.46e+06     5s
 107   3.43140348e+09  3.10239896e+07  1.04e+02 3.51e+00  1.31e+05     5s
 108   2.45263316e+09  7.84412263e+06  7.43e-02 2.34e-13  1.05e+04     5s
 109   1.63037050e+09  1.40384430e+07  6.04e-02 1.81e-12  6.97e+03     5s
 110   5.06665210e+08  1.63903558e+07  3.71e-03 1.50e-12  2.12e+03     5s
 111   2.12428393e+08  1.82853643e+07  0.00e+00 1.44e-12  8.39e+02     5s
 112   9.43962927e+07  1.91461854e+07  0.00e+00 1.64e-12  3.25e+02     5s
 113   5.99954984e+07  2.04424830e+07  0.00e+00 1.35e-12  1.71e+02     5s
 114   3.96178923e+07  2.12789422e+07  0.00e+00 1.44e-12  7.89e+01     5s
 115   3.15124790e+07  2.16345119e+07  0.00e+00 1.19e-12  4.24e+01     5s
 116   2.82787364e+07  2.22492178e+07  0.00e+00 8.76e-13  2.58e+01     5s
 117   2.59968843e+07  2.25530200e+07  0.00e+00 6.69e-13  1.47e+01     5s
 118   2.47083404e+07  2.27011436e+07  0.00e+00 6.56e-13  8.58e+00     5s
 119   2.38882779e+07  2.28651800e+07  0.00e+00 4.39e-13  4.37e+00     5s
 120   2.35032467e+07  2.29439166e+07  0.00e+00 2.95e-13  2.39e+00     5s
 121   2.33757047e+07  2.29782137e+07  0.00e+00 2.35e-13  1.70e+00     6s
 122   2.32940090e+07  2.30110957e+07  0.00e+00 1.70e-13  1.21e+00     6s
 123   2.31815938e+07  2.30229570e+07  0.00e+00 1.36e-13  6.77e-01     6s
 124   2.31195704e+07  2.30331647e+07  0.00e+00 8.26e-14  3.69e-01     6s
 125   2.30922902e+07  2.30387898e+07  0.00e+00 6.42e-14  2.28e-01     6s
 126   2.30776797e+07  2.30421270e+07  0.00e+00 5.82e-14  1.52e-01     6s
 127   2.30767019e+07  2.30422451e+07  0.00e+00 7.42e-14  1.47e-01     6s
 128   2.30706880e+07  2.30430868e+07  0.00e+00 8.13e-14  1.18e-01     6s
 129   2.30678637e+07  2.30435161e+07  0.00e+00 9.89e-14  1.04e-01     6s
 130   2.30553793e+07  2.30449089e+07  0.00e+00 7.90e-14  4.47e-02     6s
 131   2.30492252e+07  2.30463607e+07  0.00e+00 4.70e-14  1.22e-02     6s
 132   2.30473087e+07  2.30471427e+07  4.31e-07 2.89e-14  7.09e-04     6s
 133   2.30471760e+07  2.30471760e+07  4.99e-07 2.83e-14  3.86e-08     6s
 134   2.30471760e+07  2.30471760e+07  7.29e-11 2.84e-14  4.06e-14     6s

Barrier solved model in 134 iterations and 5.87 seconds
Optimal objective 2.30471760e+07

Crossover log...

   35929 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00                 6s
       0 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00                 6s

   10694 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00                 6s
       0 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00                 6s

  Push phase complete: Pinf 0.0000000e+00, Dinf 0.0000000e+00      6s

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
   46626    2.3047176e+07   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      6s

Solved in 46626 iterations and 6.18 seconds
Optimal objective  2.304717600e+07
```

Comment: By default, Gurobi uses all the cores. There's some other reason why your performance didn't improve. Please post the log.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added an example log file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the log. 134 barrier iterations is large, especially for a model of this size. My first guess is to try another algorithm like dual simplex (method=1). Although dual simplex does not benefit from multiple cores, it may be faster for your model. Simplex could also take advantage of warm-starts, assuming your models are related.

You should also try [the Parameter Tuning Tool](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/parameter_tuning_tool.html) to see if it can find additional performance improvements.

Good luck with your studies.